# Character in filename that makes it sorted in last position in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-explorer, filesystems

A common trick to have files sorted **first** in Windows Explorer is to add the `_` character as prefix, as displayed in the screenshot below.

**Question: Which character can I add to the filename to have a file always in last position, after all other files?**

Of course, adding `Z` (or `ZZ`, `ZZZ`, etc.) works, but it gives weird filenames such as `ZZZOtherInformation.txt`.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information given in the post
[What is the first character in the sort order used by Windows Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290541/what-is-the-first-character-in-the-sort-order-used-by-windows-explorer),
and especially in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54373164/165358),
is that non-English symbols follow English ones in this order:

```
Latin (ordered by Unicode value (U+xxxx))  
Greek (ordered by Unicode value (U+xxxx))  
Cyrillic (ordered by Unicode value (U+xxxx))   
Hebrew (ordered by Unicode value (U+xxxx))  
Arabic (ordered by Unicode value (U+xxxx))
```

You may then choose from these non-English alphabets any letter that you like,
for example Omega : `Ω`. Every file-name starting with this letter will
follow any file-names composed using the Latin alphabet.

Comment: True, this works with `Ω`! Is there one that looks like a separator `-`, `_`, `|` and not like a letter?

Comment: Also, can I use full UTF8 (of course except a few reserved characters `\ `, `/`, `:`, etc.) for filenames with NTFS / Windows 7? Or does the filesystem use another encoding that UTF8?  (IIRC, with Python, I noticed filesystem's filenames uses another encoding, but I don't find it anymore)

Comment: It has to be a letter, since symbols are either ignored or sorted before any letters. You may choose any that you like from any alphabet.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. `Δ` or `Ω` will be fine, then! (I don't use other greek letters anyway, so Delta will be fine).

Comment: With Greek first letters you can have folders named "**Αrchive**", "**Οld**", or "**Τrash**" that sort to the bottom (tested in Windows 10 Explorer and Google Drive). Here the first letters are U+0391 Greek Capital Letter Alpha, U+039F Greek Capital Letter Omicron, and U+03A4 Greek Capital Letter Tau respectively. The downside is that these lookalike characters might confuse people (or yourself in a few years), for example they won't match if you search for the latin script words archive/old/trash.

Answer (score 8):

This is quite old now, but I’d like to add that there *is* in fact a character that will get sorted below the latin alphabet and looks like a separator (unfortunately I can’t comment under the post where OP asked for that specifically since I don’t have enough karma here.)

It’s `一` which is the Kanji for "Ichi" / "One" in Japanese (or Chinese). Works quite well for me and looks better than greek letters.

Comment: I believe it does provide an answer to the original question. It also meets additional criteria OP specified in a comment, but that doesn’t mean it doesn’t answer the question "Which character can I add to the filename to have a file always in last position, after all other files?". The character I proposed does have that effect so I’d say it’s a valid and helpful answer, regardless of me mentioning OPs comment.

Comment: I don't think this is the "last" character and an universal answer but I removed the comment since all other answers aren't too accurate either.

Comment: Thanks. I see where you’re coming from, if taken absolutely literally it wouldn’t sort things absolutely last. But OP mentions that even just adding "ZZ" to filenames works for them, so anything sorted below the latin alphabet would be a better alternative already.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following characters, they will be sorted after many characters (Latin characters, CJK characters).

(Work in Windows 10)

```
# PowerShell
'㊀, ㊁, ㊂, ㊃, ㊄, ㊅, ㊆, ㊇, ㊈, ㊉, ㊊, ㊋, ㊌, ㊍, ㊎, ㊏, ㊐, ㊑, ㊒, ㊓, ㊔, ㊕, ㊖, ㊗, ㊘, ㊙, ㊚, ㊛, ㊜, ㊝, ㊞, ㊟, ㊠, ㊡, ㊢, ㊣, ㊤, ㊥, ㊦, ㊧, ㊨, ㊩, ㊪, ㊫, ㊬, ㊭, ㊮, ㊯, ㊰' -split ', ' | % { New-Item -Type File -Name $_}
```